# Cannot get Azure container network profile Id

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-instances

We are actually deploying container to Azure using Azure CLI and the create command as specify the sample documentation below :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet

In this dosucmentation it is clearly specify from the sample command below that when the container and the Vnet/Subnet gets created, azure create for you a Network Profile Id ( that is need for yaml deplyoement)

```
az container create --name appcontainer --resource-group myResourceGroup --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld --vnet aci-vnet --vnet-address-prefix 10.0.0.0/16 --subnet aci-subnet --subnet-address-prefix 10.0.0.0/24
```

After the container gets created successfully you are supposed to get Network profile name or ID, which you can obtain using "[az network profile list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/profile?view=azure-cli-latest#az_network_profile_list)"

Which in fact does not return anything

UPDATE :
I update m Azure CLI to 2.30 in powershell but the result is the same the output of the command return nohing even if container and vnet gets succesfully created

[Output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQDhj.png)

Thanks for your help

regards

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment.

I deployed a container to a new virtual network using the below command:

```
az container create --name appcontainer --resource-group myResourceGroup --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld --vnet aci-vnet --vnet-address-prefix 10.0.0.0/16 --subnet aci-subnet --subnet-address-prefix 10.0.0.0/24
```

The container got successfully created.

To get the Network Profile ID, I used the below command:

```
az network profile list --resource-group myResourceGroup --query [0].id --output tsv
```

[image]

In this way, we can fetch the Network Profile ID

If network profile is not getting created using CLI, try using ARM template

Comment: What error are you getting? What version of azure cli are you using?

Comment: @ramaraoAdap-MT, thanks for the feedback. What could be the reason that I am not getting the Network profile ID with exact same command as you ? I have tested from Azure CLI and powershel with Azure CLI install. Container and network gets created succesfully but the network profile command return nothing
https://watch.screencastify.com/v/IMv4OUzy5lhEVCEeBBFa

Comment: the network profile does not return any error.... just nothing
If I run the command from CLI on azure it use version 3.0
if I run the az cli from powershel, I have version 2.29

Comment: Can you upgrade az cli to 2.30.0 and try once. Also try with this command and share the output : az network profile list --resource-group myResourceGroup

Comment: I just upgrade to 2.30 and I get same result. When I run the command, it display nothing and switch me back to shell prompt ( see in attached link)
https://o365itecor-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/s_calderara_itecor_com/EVVgqFWYS19JuPr96B5aK2ABh9Xx_lsYEZXghbLqyEaVDQ?e=gPTeN7

Comment: Can you try this command : az network profile list

Comment: az network profile list return an empty array like []

Comment: Can you check the JSON view of the container instance if network profile is present or not : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hyqa.png

Comment: I do not have any Network profile entry in created container after looking at Json view
https://o365itecor-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/s_calderara_itecor_com/Ea4QGTnqyERGnSq8TB3GrloBeoJbJUO9k6vXqe8o0K_utA?e=PpEQl6

Comment: Can you try to delete this container and vnet. And try to create a new container using the same command using cli 2.30.0. check if network profile is created or not

Comment: no luck, the container gets created as normally, then by default it gets a private adress from the vnet and subnet but no network entry in json container file. This is really strange, what can it be?
 https://o365itecor-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/s_calderara_itecor_com/Ea9H-a5bFKZGklTbBObspkoBpt5furFgKJKOOVOOPJsoQg?e=LLInhG

Comment: Can you try to deploy it using ARM template?

Comment: do you have the sample ARM template to be use ? I have never done such

Comment: check if this helps : https://godatadriven.com/blog/azure-container-instance-example/

Comment: it works if I create network profile using ARM template. Azure does not create a default network profile as it is explain in documentation, or it is only used internally and not accessible by the network profile list command... strange

Comment: In my case, it got created using CLI. Using portal, network profile was not getting created. I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, once the network profile is creates, normally when you deploy a container by specifying a fixed IP adress, it should notrmally take it correct ?

Comment: As of now, fixed IP private address assignment to container instance is not supported

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me. I solve it using Azure CLI version 2.27.2. Any newer version leaves me with the same problem.
There seems to be a problem with the latest versions of the Azure CLI